# Android Navigation Components - How to pop startDestination off the back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have a single activity app that uses the Android Navigation Component for navigation. When a user launches my app, I want to show a Welcome Fragment that lets them choose how they'd like to work today (They can choose workflow A or workflow B).

Once the user chooses one of the options they are navigated to the Do Work Fragment that allows them to start working. If they click the back button at this point, I want the app to close, not to navigate back to the Welcome Fragment (The Welcome Fragment only shows on app startup).

The way I set my navigation graph up was to set the Welcome Fragment as the start destination and the Do Work Fragment as another destination on the same graph.

When the app is launched my Welcome Fragment is shown as desired, however, there doesn't seem to be a slick way to launch the Do Work Fragment from the Welcome Fragment AND pop the WelcomeFragment off the back stack so that it can't be navigated to again without actually killing and restarting the app.

What I've settled on is, from the Welcome Fragment, calling findNavController.popBackStack() and then findNavController().navigate(R.id.do_work_fragment). This seems to have the desired behavior, however it seems really weird to have to "manually" pop the back stack. At first I assumed this would never work since I figured popping the back stack with a single item on it would cause the app to close, but it appears to work just fine.

Am I overthinking this and my solution is just fine or is there a better way to solve this navigation scenario with Android's Navigation Components?

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to do a [first time user experience](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#first-time_user_experience)

Comment: @ianhanniballake Looking at FTUE example and not sure I understand it. I want to always load Welcome then nav to Do Work. The FTUE example makes it look like I have to have something analogous to main fragment (which one would it be in my case?). Should Do Work be the start dest and observe a LiveData indicating it's the first load and conditionally nav to Welcome? Then selecting an option (a or b) on Welcome will pop back stack inclusive bace to Do Work? How do I prevent a back nav from Welcome to Do Work, just set a onBackPressedDispatcher and finish the parent activity if it is called?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I understand the FTUE example, however in my app my DoWork fragment has a Google Map iwhich asks for location permissions on load. If I follow the FTUE example, I'd set Do Work as start_dest, then nav to Welcome conditionally on load, but since Do Work actually runs through its lifecycle, the map permissions will trigger and the system permission screen will show over top of my Welcome screen which is not desired. I could set some flags in a view model and prevent the map from loading until the welcome screen is dismissed, but now I'm adding logic that shouldn't really exist.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Which is totally workable, it just feels like I must be doing something wrong if I'm resorting to that. With activity transitions it was possible to launch a new activity and clear the task stack, which is more or less what I desire here. Is there not an analogous feature in navigation components?

Comment: You can do that, you just specifically shouldn't do that with the start destination of your graph as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination)